# 25.2 - documentation for "experimental cairo drawing"

Tags: images

Can anyone provide some hints on how the "experimental cairo drawing" works in recent GNU Emacs?  Specifically, what can I do to test this functionality (as requested in release docs).

```
[joe@localhost emacs-25.2]$ find ./ -name *.el | xargs grep "cairo"
./lisp/version.el:(defvar cairo-version-string)
./lisp/version.el:       (if (featurep 'cairo)
./lisp/version.el:           (format ", cairo version %s" cairo-version-string)
```

From the [NEWS](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/news/NEWS.25.1) file for 25.1:

> ** New configure option --with-cairo. This builds Emacs with Cairo drawing.  As a side effect, it provides support for built-in printing,
>   when Emacs was built with GTK+. The Emacs Cairo drawing is
>   experimental and still has some known display problems.  We encourage
>   more testing of this build and reporting any problems you find, but it
>   is not recommended for production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in NEWS, it's a configure option, so when you're compiling Emacs, pass it to configure: `./configure --with-cairo`

If you report bugs, make sure to put "cairo" in the subject line.  And check existing bugs: https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/pkgreport.cgi?package=emacs;include=subject%3Acairo

Comment: What I am wondering about is a *tactical* strategy for testing.  I.e. what sort of user operations touch the cairo code when Emacs is configured to use it?  As in my question there is effectively no mention of cairo in the `lisp` directory.  Could you update your answer to provide some user-level details?

Comment: Oh, um, displaying stuff, I guess?

Comment: Is there a good strategy for getting these examples or variants thereof to "run" (display) inside Emacs? https://www.cairographics.org/examples/

Comment: I believe Emacs can display svg files, if that helps